# Unexpected behavior of NotebookDelete

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, customization

I want to delete current and previous cells.So I make a custom function:

```
dd := (SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Previous, CellGroup]; 
  NotebookDelete[]; NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]])
```

But I'm confused why examples below do not work:

- **First**

  ```
  dd := (NotebookDelete[
     SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Previous, CellGroup]]; 
    NotebookDelete[EvaluationCell[]])
  ```
- **Second**

  ```
  dd := (obj1 = SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Previous, CellGroup];
    obj2 = EvaluationCell[]; NotebookDelete[{obj1, obj2}];)
  ```

I can not check any error in my code. And I think the usage is supported by *Mathematica*:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what exactly is your point but notice that `SelectionMove` does not return `CellObject` (or anything in general).

Comment: @Kuba You are right maybe.So how to return that `CellObject` in current selection?

Comment: `SelectedCells[]`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks very much.You help me again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `SelectionMove` does not return `CellObject` (or anything in general) that would be suitable for other *FrontEnd* related functions.

This is a problem with your examples, `obj1` is really `Null`.

But you can get to know which cell was selected after `SelectionMove`, use `SelectedCells[]`.

Here is a minimal example how would it work, create two dummy cells:

```
1
```

```
2
```

and evaluate

```
SelectionMove[First @ Cells[], All, Cell];
obj1 = SelectedCells[];
obj2 = PreviousCell[]; 
NotebookDelete[Flatten @ {obj1, obj2}];
```